# TemplateNotFound: templates/HomePage.html error when website is deployed on Google app engine but the website run fine when ran in local host

Tags: python, html, css, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy my personal website but I am running into a big error when I run my website in local host everything runs fine.But I have deployed my website via Google App but it does not work. I keep getting this error below [Here is a screenshot of the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgDfc.png)

I don't know why it is doing this because that Homepage.html file is inside of the template folder. [This a screenshot of my file path and the Python code I wrote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDoEE.png).
This the code I wrote

```
import jinja2
import os
import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import datetime
import json
import unicodedata
from google.appengine.api import users

 # the two lines of code below makes the jinja work
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=
    jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class HomePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = 
jinja_environment.get_template('templates/HomePage.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

class AboutMe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/Aboutme.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

class Contact(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('templates/Contact.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())


class Projects(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
    template = 
jinja_environment.get_template('templates/Projects.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', HomePage), #HomePage
    ('/AboutMe.html',AboutMe),
    ('/Contact.html',Contact),
    ('/Projects.html',Projects)

], debug=True)
}
```

here is my app.yaml file

```
application: israel-ali
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
# order matters always have this order
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /resources
  static_dir: static_folder

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

[enter image description here][3]

Comment: Please paste the code and not just an image of your code.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The same applies to the traceback - don't post images of text unless the image contains relevant visual information.

Comment: side note: I'd add `templates` to the `jinja2.FileSystemLoader()` call so that `.get_template()` can use just the template filename without its path. Just cosmetic.

Answer (score 3):

Filenames are case sensitive on GAE.

Your code seeks a template called `HomePage.html` and (what I suspect to be) the actual template is called `Homepage.html`. And you have a similar problem with `Aboutme.html` vs. `AboutMe.html`.

You just need to use the actual filename in `.get_template()`.

Answer (score 2):

Is the operating system you're using locally one that doesn't treat case in filenames as significant? If so, those `template_get` lines need to specify filenames *exactly* as they are on the filesystem.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed the bug that I had.